# small question about jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

When I see the jqgrid demo, the columnnames often on the top of the jqgrid.behind it is the searchtoolbar.Now ,I want to change the position of the cloumnnames and the searchtoolbar.I want  to put the searchtoolbar on the top of the jqgrid.
I look at the source code of jqgrid in C#, and I see the JQgridRenderer.cs, but fail to find the code about it.Can anyone help me ?thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You question in not so easy in the implementation.

You can try the following code

```
var grid = $("#list"), i, 
    $htableTHead = grid.closest('div.ui-jqgrid-view')
        .find('table.ui-jqgrid-htable>thead'),
    $lables = $htableTHead.children('tr.ui-jqgrid-labels'),
    $thColumn = $lables.children('th'),
    $searchToolbar = $htableTHead.children('tr.ui-search-toolbar'),
    $thToolbar = $searchToolbar.children('th'),
    l = Math.min($thToolbar.length, $thColumn.length),
    h = grid[0].grid.headers;

for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
    $thToolbar[i].style.cssText = $thColumn[i].style.cssText;
    $thColumn[i].style.cssText = "";
    h[i].el = $thToolbar[i];
}
$htableTHead.children('tr.ui-search-toolbar').prependTo($htableTHead);
```

As the result you will have

[image]

see the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchToolbarOnTop0.htm).

It's close to what you want, but if you will try to use `sortable: true` for example you will receive problems which can't be fixed without changing of some jqGrid code. So I can't grantee that the code above will work in all another situations.